# How to pass data using dll between projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, asp.net-web-api

I have a solution that has two projects, Windows Forms and Web API. I need to pass some data that I've collected in windows form to Web API, is it possible using dll, if so how?

How can I start the Windows Forms from the Web API?

thk

Comment: You really need some understanding about what Windows Forms and Web API applications are.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You want to pass data from "Windows Forms" to "Web API" and at the same time you want the "Web API" to start the "Windows forms"???? Something is wrong here...

Comment: it sounds like you have a WinForms client that collects some data from a user and you want to save that for use by your web api. In this case you'd probably want to expose some kind of submit method for your web api and the data would be passed in as parameters. the api would probably save to a database or some other storage mechanism

Comment: you're saying like a method and in my web api call it? but i also have to run my windows form, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the concept of DLL File is to link your program with a shared library that has its functions, methods, etc. to be reused with your piece of code..

You can't really pass "Data" through a DLL file, however, the simplest way to pass simple data from one program to another is using Input/Output files, you can just Write your data in a text file with the first Program (in this case the Windows Form) and read it with the second one (the Web API)

Comment: my situations is this: i have a windows form that collects data to connect to a database and the columns that i have to use, after that i have to present those column values in a web page, for that i've been told to use a web api, to get the column values and present it. since i've been told to use dll, what i was thinking was from my web api call the windows form to get that data and receive it in my web api to do the rest of the work

Comment: you can easily access tables from SQL Server Database using the Website if you're working on ASP.NET, just connect with the SQL Server and do the Queries you want.

Comment: but for that i need the info that was inserted/selected in the windows form

Comment: what i was thinking it could be done was i reference the dll in both projects, the windows form would write that data into the dll and the web api would read it